# How to find the max of the sum for each group in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database with tables ARTIST and SONG. Each song has a number of reproductions, an album associated and the artist_id that owns it. I want to get for each artist, the album that has the highest number of reproductions counting al of its songs. The tables are something like this:

Artist:

| Artist_Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Ignacio Guitar |
| 2 | Rosalia |
| 3 | Makande |

Song:

| Artist_Id | Name | N_reproductions | Name_album |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Song1 | 10 | Album1 |
| 1 | Song2 | 15 | Album1 |
| 1 | Song3 | 13 | Album1 |
| 1 | Song4 | 20 | Album2 |
| 1 | Song5 | 12 | Album2 |
| 1 | Song6 | 25 | Album2 |
| 2 | Song7 | 17 | Album3 |
| 2 | Song8 | 21 | Album3 |
| 2 | Song9 | 20 | Album4 |
| 2 | Song10 | 25 | Album4 |
| 2 | Song11 | 31 | Album4 |

So the result I want to get would be

| Name | Name_album |
| --- | --- |
| Ignacio Guitar | Album2 |
| Rosalia | Album4 |

So far I've tried this:

```sql
SELECT a.name, s.name_alb
  FROM artist a
  JOIN song s
    ON (a.artist_id = s.artist_id)
 GROUP BY a.artist_id, a.name, s.name_alb
HAVING SUM(s.n_reproductions) = (SELECT MAX(SUM(s1.n_reproductions))
                                   FROM song s1
                                  WHERE s1.artist_id = a.artist_id
                                    AND s1.name_alb = s.name_alb
                                  GROUP BY s1.artist_id, s1.name_alb);
```

but this returns every album from every artist instead.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a useful addition

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? Is this Oracle? (This is the ony DBMS I know to allow `MAX(SUM(something))`).

Comment: Sorry, I've added the tables and they show in preview but not in the final post, don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your subquery you are looking at one album with

```
WHERE S1.ARTIST_ID = A.ARTIST_ID AND S1.NAME_ALB = S.NAME_ALB
```

Of this you get the

```
SUM(S1.N_REPRODUCTIONS)
```

which is one value in spite of

```
GROUP BY S1.ARTIST_ID, S1.NAME_ALB)
```

because it is only one album you are looking at.

Oracle allows another aggregation directly without having to write a subquery. You use this to get the maximum sum, but as there is only one sum, you just get the album's reproductions count. So you end up with

```
HAVING <album's reproduction count> = <album's reproduction count>
```

The easiest approach to get an artist's album(s) with the maximum reproduction sum is probably to get that maximum via `MAX OVER`. Then you can just filter those rows and only keep albums that have that maximum sum.

```
SELECT a.name, r.name_alb
FROM
(
  SELECT
    artist_id, name_alb,
    SUM(n_reproductions) AS sum_repros,
    MAX(SUM(n_reproductions)) OVER (PARTITION BY artist_id) AS max_sum_repros
  FROM song
  GROUP BY artist_id, name_alb
) r
JOIN artist a ON a.artist_id = r.artist_id
WHERE r.sum_repros = r.max_sum_repros
ORDER BY a.name, r.name_alb;
```

The same aggregated for the case an artist has two or more top albums:

```
SELECT a.name, LISTAGG(r.name_alb, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.name_alb) AS albums
FROM
(
  SELECT
    artist_id, name_alb,
    SUM(n_reproductions) AS sum_repros,
    MAX(SUM(n_reproductions)) OVER (PARTITION BY artist_id) AS max_sum_repros
  FROM song
  GROUP BY artist_id, name_alb
) r
JOIN artist a ON a.artist_id = r.artist_id
WHERE r.sum_repros = r.max_sum_repros
GROUP BY a.name
ORDER BY a.name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/b5JI5erl

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(a.name) AS name,
       s.name_album
FROM   artist a
       INNER JOIN song s
       ON (a.artist_id = s.artist_id)
GROUP BY a.artist_id, s.name_album
ORDER BY
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         PARTITION BY a.artist_id
         ORDER BY SUM(n_reproductions) DESC
       )
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Artist (Artist_Id, Name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Ignacio Guitar' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Rosalia' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Makande' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Song (Artist_Id, Name, N_reproductions, Name_album) AS
SELECT 1, 'Song1',  10, 'Album1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Song2',  15, 'Album1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Song3',  13, 'Album1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Song4',  20, 'Album2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Song5',  12, 'Album2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Song6',  25, 'Album2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Song7',  17, 'Album3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Song8',  21, 'Album3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Song9',  20, 'Album4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Song10', 25, 'Album4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Song11', 31, 'Album4' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| NAME | NAME_ALBUM |
| --- | --- |
| Ignacio Guitar | Album2 |
| Rosalia | Album4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tn2KhvPE)